# "Read Time" getting started Tutorial not working for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

The issue I am having is after I load the unpacked extension to chrome and attempt to use it, the "Reading time" option is grey and unclickable. Here is the link to the tutorial I was following:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/tut-reading-time/

[Here is an image of what occurs when I click on my "Reading time" chrome extension. The "Reading time" in the top right corner is grey and unclickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruQj4.png)

What am I missing?

I have copied everything from the tutorial so I feel it is probably something new that was added to one of the packages or something like that, but I could be wrong. [Attached is the file structure that is shown in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPGGm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal. It doesn't need to click an icon.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see now. I didn't notice that difference. I thought, it being an extension, some popup would occur when I clicked the icon in the top right. Thanks for explaining that.